# Обновление данных в объекте после изменения его в PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

Доброго времени суток!

Второй день бьюсь в изучении WPF PropertyGrid от xceed. Документации по нему мало, как и знаний у меня по WPF, но хотелось бы решить данную задачу.

Создал объект, поместил его в PropertyGrid, реализовал свой редактор полей свойств объекта. В редакторе отображаются записи, я их успешно выбираю, но к полям свойств объекта они не привязываются.

Тестовый пример ниже.

**Редактор свойств**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestExtendedWPFTools.DropDownControl" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300" 
             x:Name="_uc">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=_uc}"></ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Editors;
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid;

namespace TestExtendedWPFTools
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для DropDownControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DropDownControl : UserControl, ITypeEditor
    {
        public DropDownControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cb.Items.Add(new Field()
                {
                    Key = i.ToString(),
                    Value = string.Format("Record: {0}", i),
                });
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(Field), typeof(DropDownControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

        public Field Value
        {
            get
            {
                return (Field)GetValue(ValueProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public FrameworkElement ResolveEditor(PropertyItem propertyItem)
        {
            var binding = new Binding("Value");
            binding.Source = propertyItem;
            binding.Mode = propertyItem.IsReadOnly ? BindingMode.OneWay : BindingMode.TwoWay;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, DropDownControl.ValueProperty, binding);

            return this;
        }

    }
}
```

**Редактируемый объект**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestExtendedWPFTools
{
    public class DBInfo
    {
        [Editor(typeof(DropDownControl), typeof(DropDownControl))]
        public Field Access
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestExtendedWPFTools
{
    public class Field
    {
        public string Key
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //public override string ToString()
        //{
        //    return Value;
        //}
    }
}
```

На всякий случай, **главное окно программы**

```
<Window x:Class="TestExtendedWPFTools.MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:xc="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Width="200" Height="32" Click="Button_Click">Тестовая кнопка</Button>
        <xc:PropertyGrid x:Name="grid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateProperties="True" ShowSearchBox="False">

        </xc:PropertyGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>



/// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// &lt;/summary&gt;
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dbinfo = new DBInfo();
            grid.SelectedObject = dbinfo;
        }

        public DBInfo dbinfo
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dbinfo != null)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что вы вообще сделать то хотите?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, хочу отдать Propertygrid объект, изменить его поля, а после объект сохранить. В WinForms стандартный PropertyGrid разобрался несколько лет назад, а сейчас есть необходимость перейти на wpf, вот переписываю код на него.

Comment: написал ответ...проверьте, должно работать...но будет лучше если вы ознакомитесь с литературой по WPF и перепишите код нормально

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, спасибо. Читаю сейчас второпях книгу, общий принцип понимаю, но опыта мало в написании, потому в некоторых местах может оказаться быдлокод. По мере переписывания буду подтягивать знания и возвращаться обратно, чтобы исправить то, что уже написал.

Comment: Когда что-то будет непонятно - спрашивайте, сайт для этого и предназначен :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы использовать привязку для свойства `Text` используйте свойство `SelectedItem`.

Т.е. замените:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=_uc}"></ComboBox>
```

на:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb" SelectedItem="{Binding Value}" />
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, работает. Жутко тупанул используя пример с textbox переправляя на combobox...